# Does ideal reduction commute with intersection?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, groebner-basis, computational-algebra, groebner-generators

Let $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,...,T_n]$ be the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{Z}$, and $\mathbb{F}_p[T_1,...,T_n]$ be the ring of polynomials over $\mathbb{F}_p$, with the canonical projection

$p:\mathbb{Z}[T_1,...,T_n]\rightarrow \mathbb{F}_p[T_1,...,T_n].$

Let $I=(f_1,...,f_r)$ be an ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,...,T_n]$, then we define $\overline{I}:=(\overline{f_1},...,\overline{f_r})=I^e=p(I)$ be the reduction ideal of $I$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[T_1,...,T_n]$.

My question is, for ideals $I$ and $J$ of $\mathbb{Z}[T_1,...,T_n]$, in what kind of condition, we have $\overline{I\cap J}=\overline{I}\cap \overline{J}$?

(I think the above equality can not be true in general, however if we ask some condition of the generator of $I$ and $J$, for example with trivial content of grobner basis, maybe some good thing happen?)

Comment: The image of the intersection is always contained in the intersection of the images. For an example whete you do not get equality, take $n=1$, $I=(T_1)$, $ J=(T_1+p)$.

Comment: Deer Magidin, yeah I know it can not be true in general, I just want to ask a condition ot criterion for this equality. For example, one may surggest that the generators of ideals have coefficients as "1", or say something to their grobner basis

Comment: An easy condition is that $(I+J)\cap (p)=(0)$.

Comment: For another easy example to verify, in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$ you have $\langle x-y \rangle \cap \langle x+y \rangle = \langle x^2-y^2 \rangle$.  But in $\mathbb{F}_2[x,y]$ the two ideals are equal so the intersection is $\langle x-y \rangle$ instead of $\langle x^2-y^2 \rangle = \langle x-y \rangle^2$.